# Heroku Deployment Error: "Could not find Required file: index.html"

Tags: node.js, heroku, create-react-app, spotify

I'm building a Spotify connected app based on nodeJs and react and i'm having issues deploying my application to nodeJs. I'm getting an error on deploying to heroku.

`main error`

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.14.2
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 16.14.2...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.14.2...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.5.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > spotify-node@1.0.0 postinstall
remote:        > cd client && npm install
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        added 1660 packages, and audited 1661 packages in 39s
remote:        
remote:        235 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        80 vulnerabilities (75 moderate, 5 high)
remote:        
remote:        To address issues that do not require attention, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:        
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:        
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote:        added 133 packages, and audited 134 packages in 47s
remote:        
remote:        19 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:        
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > spotify-node@1.0.0 build
remote:        > NODE_ENV=production cd client/ && npm install && npm run build
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 1661 packages in 3s
remote:        
remote:        235 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        80 vulnerabilities (75 moderate, 5 high)
remote:        
remote:        To address issues that do not require attention, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:        
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:        
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote:        > client@0.1.0 build
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Could not find a required file.
remote:          Name: index.html
remote:          Searched in: /tmp/build_d689409b/client/public
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to spotify-node.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/spotify-node.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/spotify-node.git'
```

here is the folder structure:

```
client
 |- public
 |- src
   - components
   - pages
     |- index.js
   - spotify
     |- api.js
     |- auth.js
node_modules
server
 |- index.js
.env
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
Procfile
README.md
```

`server/index.js`

```
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8888;
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID || "387141873123719827tte81531d611";
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const REDIRECT_URI =
  process.env.REDIRECT_URI ||
  "https://spotify-node-88afa51b6fea.herokuapp.com/callback";
const FRONTEND_URI = process.env.FRONTEND_URI;

const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const axios = require("axios");
const express = require("express");
const querystring = require("querystring");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const history = require("connect-history-api-fallback");

const app = express();

// Priority serve any static files

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));

app
  .use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")))
  .use(cors())
  .use(cookieParser())
  .use(
    history({
      verbose: true,
      rewrites: [
        { from: /\/login/, to: "/login" },
        { from: /\/callback/, to: "/callback" },
        { from: /\/refresh_token/, to: "/refresh_token" },
      ],
    })
  )
  .use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));

/**
 * Generate a random string containing numn  and letters
 * @param {number} length the length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */

function generateRandomString(length) {
  let result = "";
  const characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < length) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    counter += 1;
  }
  return result;
}

const stateKey = "spotify_auth_sate";

/**
 * Routes Config
 */

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, world! This is a new spotify app!");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  const state = generateRandomString(16);
  const scope = "user-read-private user-read-email";

  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  const queryParams = querystring.stringify({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    response_type: "code",
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    state: state,
    scope: scope,
    show_dialog: false,
  });

  res.redirect(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${queryParams}`);
});

app.get("/callback", (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code || null;

  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    data: querystring.stringify({
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    }),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: `Basic ${new Buffer.from(
        `${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`
      ).toString("base64")}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const { access_token, token_type, refresh_token } = response.data;

        const queryParams = querystring.stringify({
          access_token,
          refresh_token,
        });

        // Redirect to app
        // pass along the  tokens in query params

        res.redirect(`${FRONTEND_URI}?${queryParams}`);
      } else {
        res.redirect(
          `/?${querystring.stringify({
            error: "invalid_token",
          })}`
        );
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});

app.get("/refresh_token", (req, res) => {
  const { refresh_token } = req.query;

  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    data: querystring.stringify({
      grant_type: "refresh_token",
      refresh_token: refresh_token,
    }),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: `Basic ${new Buffer.from(
        `${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`
      ).toString("base64")}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      res.send(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});

// Returns all remaining routs to the react app to be handled
// by react router.

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/public", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, (_) => {
  console.log("listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

`client/src/index.js`

The spotify/api file houses the api calls to the spotify api and the auth file manages the tokens and login state throughout the entire application.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { accessToken, logout } from "../spotify/auth";
import { getCurrentUserProfile } from "../spotify/api";
import { catchErrors } from "../utils/utils";

import "../styles/App.css";

function App() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(accessToken);

    const getProfile = async () => {
      const { data } = await getCurrentUserProfile();
      setProfile(data);
    };

    catchErrors(getProfile);
  }, [profile]);

  const LOGIN_URI =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? "https://spotify-node-88afa51b6fea.herokuapp.com/login"
      : "http://localhost:8888/login";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {!token ? (
          <div>
            <img
              src={
                "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6775700000ee855ed27974479c5f83d6bbf47e"
              }
              className="App-logo"
              alt="logo"
            />
            <p></p>
            <a className="App-link" href={LOGIN_URI} rel="noopener noreferrer">
              Login to Spotify
            </a>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            {profile && (
              <section>
                <h1>{profile.display_name} is Logged in</h1>
                <p>he has only {profile.followers.total} followers</p>
                <img src={profile.images[0].url} alt="" />
              </section>
            )}
            <div>
              <span onClick={() => logout()}>Logout</span>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The base package.json hosts some extra configuration for the entire  application "client + server" which is shown below:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "spotify-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/reallifenero/spotify-node.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.2"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "client/node_modules"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "server": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "postinstall": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production cd client/ && npm install && npm run build",
    "start-server": "node server/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Nero - <twitter.com/reallifenro>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/reallifenero/spotify-node/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/reallifenero/spotify-node#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```